# Objective-c and C reference help

Tags: objective-c, c

hey guys im new to this site and new to the IOS development. i have prior programing experience mainly VB.net and some basic C, what i need is a really good quick access reference for everything obj-c.

any kind of help is greatly appreciated!

Thank You, 
msquared86

Comment: Lots of people ask this question; see if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c/69951#69951) is helpful for you.

Comment: The tutorials in this site are my favorites for beginners http://cocoadevcentral.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Up and Running: Objective-C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596804792) is what I used to cut my teeth on.  Great book to get you started.  All those Beginning iPhone books are worthless for teaching you Objective-C.  Get a real Objective-C book and *then* start reading those other books.  For $5 you can [purchase the iOS ebook](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cocoa-objective-c-up-running/id362352239?mt=8).  Best $5 I have ever spent.

Comment: thanks so much to both of you the up and running: objective-c and cocoa book is amazing and has taught me alot already

Answer (score 1):

What *exactly* do you want to learn about? If it's just the basics of how to use Objective-C and Cocoa, try Apple's [Introduction to the Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).

For *everything* Objective-C? http://developer.apple.com contains gigabytes of documentation about Objective-C, the Cocoa frameworks, and the secondary Objective-C-based frameworks on Apple's operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a *reference* you are after, everything you need is in the Xcode/SDK download.  The `developer documentation` menu item under `Help` provides access. However, I personally don't think the search is very good.  If you are on line, you can Google developer.apple.com for the same docs.  For example the search term:

```
site:developer.apple.com ios nsstring
```

will take you to the class reference for NSString.